# If /usr partition not specified, does it go on same partition as root by default?

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation, root

I plan to install Fedora Linux on a machine with an SSD and an HDD. `/boot`, and the root will have their own partitions on the SSD.

If I want `/usr` to be on same partition as `/`, will that occur by default if I set the root mountpoint on an SSD partition and don't specify anything with `/usr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All directories are mounted under `/` and will be on the same volume. The only exception is when you create and format a partition and use a mount point. Then the filesystem on that partition will be used instead.

`/usr` is no exception to this rule.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you do not provide physical partitions for a directory (mountpoint) during installation then they go on whatever media (hard drive) is specified for the root partition (`/`).